# How to slideup <div> tag using jQuery "MOBILE 1.3.0?

Tags: jquery-mobile, html, mobile, slideup

Could you please guide me (an example is much appreciated) as to how i can achieve the Slide up effect on a  tag like the one in jQuery 1.9.1 using jQuery MOBILE 1.3.0.

I need to do like the 1st example in this page http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

I read the slideup but how to do it for a  tag.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

I know this would be simple but i am new to jQuery. Just couldn't get it done in the mobile API.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow? Can you show your code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you looking for? **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Cw3sj/)**

Markup

```
<a data-role="button" id="clickme">Click here</a>

<br/>

// this div will slideup.
<div id="test">
 <img src="anyimg.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Code

```
$('#clickme').click(function () {
 $('#test').slideUp('slow'); // or fast, or leave it blank
});
```